# Return type ambiguity

Tags: java, return-type, cloneable

Consider the following code from The Java Programming Language book

```
public class MyClass extends HerClass implements Cloneable {
   public MyClass clone()
       throws CloneNotSupportedException {
       return (MyClass) super.clone();
   }
   // ...
}
```

When the overiding clone() function already species the return type as MyClass then what is the requirement of specifying it again in the return statement ?
Also since the clone of Myclass's super class object is being created (cause clone() is being called wrt superclass), how can it be of Myclass type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting, it depends on `HerClass`'s implementation of `clone`, it may use reflection. If `HerClass` is not that intelligent this cannot work... you know the implementation of `HerClass`?

Comment: no actually...there isn't the HerClass implementation of clone(). But the question whatever the implementation might be but could it be of MyClass type? How can a superclass return a subclass object?

Answer (score 1):

Because `clone()` returns an object of class Object, and you must cast it to the correct type. But you know it is an object of type MyClass, so that cast is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you're right: as you have to specify the type of function return values the compiler could try and perform the correction automatically. On the other hand requiring an explicit conversion helps identify possible errors.

Unless you have specific requirements the `clone()` method of the `Object` class already does the right thing, i.e. it creates an object of the correct class and copies all the non-static attributes in the cloned object. However it cannot return it as a derived type because at compile time that type is not known to the `Object` class itself.

It is true that the `clone()` method could have been provided automatically for all classes, but sometimes you don't want it to be available and at other times you want to override the default behaviour; for instance you might have an `id` attribute in your class that you want to be different for each instance of your class even when cloned. Having to override the `clone()` method gives you a place where you can implement such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `clone()` method in [Object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) returns an `Object`. However you can return your subclass in clone() because it extends an Object. If the method in `MyClass` looked like this

```
public Object clone()
```

Then it would still be a valid cloneable object and it would work. You wouldn't need to cast anything. The interface, `Cloneable` is just a marker interface, which means it doesn't actually have any methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your easy question first: why is `super.clone()` cast to `MyClass`?  That's because the declaration of `HerClass.clone()` specified a returned value of `HerClass`, so you must cast it to the right type.

Now, for the more difficult question: how can `super.clone()` actually return an instance of `MyClass`?  I actually had a hard time finding the answer, but I did somewhat find an answer in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch. There is still some "magic" in the background of `Object.clone()` that I don't quite understand.

Item 11 from the book:

> In practice, programmers assume that if they extend a class and invoke
>   super.clone from the subclass, the returned object will be an instance
>   of the subclass. The only way a superclass can provide this
>   functionality is to return an object obtained by calling super.clone.
>   If a clone method returns an object created by a constructor, it will
>   have the wrong class. Therefore, **if you override the clone method in a
>   nonfinal class, you should return an object obtained by invoking
>   super.clone**. If all of a class’s superclasses obey this rule, then
>   invoking super.clone will eventually invoke Object’s clone method,
>   creating an instance of the right class.

I originally tried to answer your question by writing a program without knowing you always had to call `super.clone()`.  My homemade clone method for `HerClass` was returning a new instance of `HerClass` generated from a constructor (`new HerClass()`).  The code compiled, but it failed at execution when I was trying to cast `(MyClass) super.clone()`.   Only methods that are chained down from `Object.clone()` can return a value that is an instance of one of their **subtype**.

Note that if `HerClass.clone()` is not explicitly implemented, by default it simply returns `Object.clone()`.  The default method has `protected` access, but since you are calling it from a subclass, it's not a problem.